# Just added FileField to models and now can't login to admin on http://

Tags: python, django, ssl, django-models, nginx

I've just added a FileField model to my models.py file:

`header_image = models.FileField(upload_to='blog/%Y/%m/%d', null=True, blank=True)`

For local development I have setup a media nginx config so my MEDIA settings in local settings.py is:

`MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '../../app/media'))
MEDIA_URL = 'http://local-media-david.ingledow.co.uk/'`

When I try and log in to the admin or upload the file from the admin, I get the following error:

```
Forbidden (403)
CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.

Referer checking failed - http://local-david.ingledow.co.uk/admin/ does not match https://local-david.ingledow.co.uk/.
```

My admin for my local development is at:

`http://local-david.ingledow.co.uk/admin/`

The only way to get it to work is to go to:

`https://local-david.ingledow.co.uk/admin/` (**https://**)

#### NGINX Config

```
server {
    listen 127.0.0.1:8080;
    server_name local-static-david.ingledow.co.uk;
    location / {
        alias /Users/dingledow/Sites/my_site2/srv/static/;
        autoindex on;
        add_header    Cache-Control  private;
        expires 0;
        gzip on;
        gzip_http_version   1.1;
        gzip_proxied any;
        gzip_comp_level 2;
        gzip_min_length  1100;
        gzip_buffers 16 8k;
        gzip_types text/plain text/css application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript image/gif image/png image/jpg image/jpeg;
        gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6].(?!.*SV1)";
        gzip_vary on;
    }
}

server {
    listen 127.0.0.1:8080;
    server_name local-media-david.ingledow.co.uk;
    location / {
        alias /Users/dingledow/Sites/my_site2/app/media/;
        autoindex on;
        add_header    Cache-Control  private;
        expires 0;
        gzip on;
        gzip_http_version   1.1;
        gzip_proxied any;
        gzip_comp_level 2;
        gzip_min_length  1100;
        gzip_buffers 16 8k;
        gzip_types text/plain text/css application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript image/gif image/png image/jpg image/jpeg;
        gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6].(?!.*SV1)";
        gzip_vary on;
    }
}
```

#### Folder Structure

[image: Folder Structure]

#### Settings: base.py

```
 import os
from os import environ
import dj_database_url

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))

SECRET_KEY = environ.get(
    'SECRET_KEY',
    'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX')

# allow debug to be set from env config
DEBUG = True if environ.get('DEBUG') is True else False

TEMPLATE_DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['.herokuapp.com', '.ingledow.co.uk', ]

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'gunicorn',
    'south',
    'blog',
    'markdown_deux',
    'storages',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'app.urls'

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'app.wsgi.application'

DATABASES = {}
DATABASES['default'] = dj_database_url.config()

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-gb'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = False

USE_L10N = False

USE_TZ = True

SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')

STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'django.contrib.staticfiles.storage.StaticFilesStorage'

STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder'
)

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '../templates/'),
)
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
}
```

#### Setting: local.py

from base import *

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']

DEBUG = True

SOUTH_TESTS_MIGRATE = False

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': 'app.db',
    }
}

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '../../srv/assets'),
)

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '../../srv/static'))
STATIC_URL = 'http://local-static-david.ingledow.co.uk/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '../../app/media'))
MEDIA_URL = 'http://local-media-david.ingledow.co.uk/'
```

This is not ideal because the Admin styles aren't viewing and I always get an SSL warning.

How do I set up FileField model without having to have SSL?  Do I have to buy an SSL certificate?

Comment: Do you have `CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE= True` in your settings?

Comment: @skzryzg Afraid that didn't work either.

Comment: No. Dont set that to true unless you have an ssl certificate setup. Let me look again at yourqestion

Comment: @skzryzg Set it to both True and False and neither work. I've added more detail above: `Referer checking failed - http://local-david.ingledow.co.uk/admin/ does not match https://local-david.ingledow.co.uk/.`

Comment: I've tried this: `USE_X_FORWARDED_HOST = True` but that also does not work.

Comment: Could you post your settings? And `../../app` seems a bit odd. Why are you doing that?

Comment: @skzryzg I've added my nginx config as well

Comment: @skzryzg Added my folder structure and settings files

Comment: Are you behind a proxy? And seriously, why do ypu keep using ` ../` in your path joins?

Comment: This question appears to belong on another site in the Stack Exchange network because its not about programming. Perhaps [Super User](https://www.superuser.com/) or [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/).